# Is f(x)dx in integral a differential?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, differential

Is $dx$ in $\int f(x)dx$ a differential of the identity function? In Zorich analysis, it is said that if $dF = f(x)dx$, then $\int dF=\int f(x)dx$. This only makes sense if $dx$ actually represents a differential, so that $f(x)dx$ is actually a function that maps each point into a linear function (i.e $\mathbb{R}\to(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})$). So in some sense we are integrating against not a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (or in particular to the set of linear functions), otherwise th $\int dF$ and the equality $\int dF = \int f(x)dx$ won't make sense.
Is this true or am I mising something here.

Comment: Your conjecture is fascinating!

Comment: @Aruralreader so is it true or not?

Comment: What question would you ask if Leibniz had invented another notation? Say $I(f)$ for the 
 anti-derivative, and $I(f,a,b)$ for the definte integral.

Comment: @KurtG. It's not about notation. Zorich explicitly state that when $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, we have $dF(x) = f(x)dx$ (which makes sense since it is just differential). And then Zorich wrote $\int dF(x) = \int f(x)dx$. Thus the only reasonable interpretation is that $dx$ and $dF$ here represents differential, otherwise you can't really interchange $f(x)dx$ with $dF(x)$.

Comment: One cannot know every book and I don't know Zorich. Smells like yet another attempt to avoid formally introducing differental forms.

Comment: My (*super subjective/personal*) suggestion: If you just think the meaning of $\int f(x){\rm d}x$ as a family of functions $\{F(x): F'(x)=f(x)\}$ (or equivalently $\{F(x)+C: C\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where $F$ is a *fixed* function s.t. $F'(x)=f(x)$), and think $\int f(x){\rm d}g(x)$ (where $g$ is differentiable) as simply **an alternative notation** for $\int f(x)g'(x){\rm d}x$, then this will *not* cause any problem.